# Extracting text from html straight into a variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a line of text from a html file straight into a variable, however, I have found no solution to the problem despite hours of searching. Beautiful Soup looks helpful, how would I be able to simply pick out a desired string as an input and then extract it from the html source right into a variable?

I've been trying to use request.text and Beutiful soup to scrape the entire page but it seems there is no function to directly do it.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def extract(url):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return [item.text for item in soup.find_all('<DIV ALIGN="justify"')]
```

```
<HMTL>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>webpage1</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFf" LINK="006666" ALINK="8B4513" VLINK="006666">
<TABLE WIDTH="75%" ALIGN="center">
<TR>
<TD>
<DIV ALIGN="center"><H1>STARTING . . . </H1></DIV>


<DIV ALIGN="justify"><P>There are lots of ways to create web pages using already coded programmes. These lessons will teach you how to use the underlying HyperText Markup Language -  HTML. 
<BR>
<P>HTML isn't computer code, but is a language that uses US English to enable texts (words, images, sounds) to be inserted and formatting such as colo(u)r and centre/ering to be written in. The process is fairly simple; the main difficulties often lie in small mistakes - if you slip up while word processing your reader may pick up your typos, but the page will still be legible. However, if your HTML is inaccurate the page may not appear - writing web pages is, at the least, very good practice for proof reading!</P>
```

When I run I would like for it to return the string

```
<P>There are lots of ways to create web pages
```

Comment: Your function returns a list of strings, not a single string. You can use `"".join()` to combine them to get a single string.

Comment: Your `find_all()` syntax doesn't look correct. I think it should be `find_all('div', align="justify")`